# Rails: Calling methods in a model in a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please, I really don't know how best to achieve refactoring this code following the best rails practices. I am trying to call some methods that are defined in a model in my rails application in a different controller.

I have a **Donations model** and a **Dashboard Controller** and I would like to display some data about donations on the dashboard. I want to achieve this by defining the data that I want in some methods and scopes in the **Donations model** and then call them in the **Dashboard controller** and then make them available in the *Dashboard views**.

But I realized that no data about donation gets displayed on the dashboard, which may be as a result of the fact that the methods in the **Donations model** doesn't get exposed or are not available to the **Dashboard controller** when they are called, since they are a different model and different controller.

Here is my code

**Donations Model**

```
class Donation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :program
  scope :paid_count, -> { where(payment: true).count }
  scope :unpaid_count, -> { where(payment: false).count }
  scope :paid_sum, -> { where(payment: true).sum(:amount) }
  scope :deployed_sum, -> { where(deployment: true).sum(:amount) }
  scope :not_deployed_sum, -> { where(deployment: false, payment: true).sum(:amount) }

  def self.deployed_donations_percent
    (deployed_sum.to_f / paid_sum.to_f) * 100
  end

  def self.not_deployed_donations_percent
    (not_deployed_sum.to_f / paid_sum.to_f) * 100
  end
end
```

**Dashboard Controller**

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Paid Donations in Chart
    @paid_donations = Donation.paid_count
    # Unpaid Donations in Chart
    @unpaid_donations = Donation.unpaid_count
    # Total Donations Sum
    @total_donations_sum = Donation.paid_sum
    # Deployed Donations
    @deployed_donations = Donation.deployed_sum
    # Not Deployed Donations
    @not_deployed_donations = Donation.not_deployed_sum
    # Deployed Donations Percentage
    @deployed_donations_percent = Donation.deployed_donations_percent
    # Not Deployed Donations Percentage
    @not_deployed_donations_percent = Donation.not_deployed_donations_percent
    @total_donations = Donation.count
    # Paid Donations
    @paid_donations = Donation.paid_count
    # Unpaid Donations
    @unpaid_donations = Donation.unpaid_count

    # All Programs
    @programs = Program.all
  end
end
```

**Dashboard Index**

```
<h2>
    DASHBOARD
</h2>

  <h4>Overall Donations</h4>
  <%#= area_chart @donations.map { |pay|{name: pay.payment, data: @donations.where(payment: pay).group_by_day(:created_at).count}}, discrete: true %>
  <%= line_chart Donation.group(:payment).group_by_day(:created_at).count

   <h4>Total Donations</h4>
    <%= number_with_delimiter(@total_donations_sum, :delimiter => ',') %>

    <h4>Deployed</h4>
     <%= number_with_delimiter(@deployed_donations, :delimiter => ',') %>

    <div>
      <%= @deployed_donations_percent.round %>>
    </div>

    <h4>Undeployed</h4>
    <%= number_with_delimiter(@not_deployed_donations, :delimiter => ',') %>

    <div>
      <%= @not_deployed_donations_percent.round %>
    </div>

<h4>Total Donations</h4>
<header>
  <%= @total_donations %>
</header>

<h4>Paid Donations</h4>
<header>
  <%= @paid_donations %>
</header>

<h4>Unpaid Donations</h4>
<header>
  <%= @unpaid_donations %>
</header>

PROGRAMS
<td>Program Name</td>
<td>Sponsored</td>

</tr>
  <% @programs.each do |program| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= program.name %></td>
<td><%= program.donations.count %></td>
```

Please, I would greatly appreciate some help on how to refactor this code and get the **Donations model** methods exposed to the **Dashboard Controller**. Thank you.

Comment: "result of the fact that the methods in the Donations model doesn't get exposed or are not available to the Dashboard controller" - nonsense. No such thing as model being available only in "its" controller. Might be as simple as you not using those instance vars in the view.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry about that line. So how do I fix the issue please, I am not an expert in ruby on rails yet.

Comment: Use the variables in your view

Comment: I am already calling the instance variables of the Dashboard controller on the view, but no luck yet. Do you have a better way to go about this?

Comment: "I am already calling the instance variables" - I don't think so. Else you'd be seeing the data. Show the view. If it's big, then only the relevant parts (where you claim you use the variables)

Comment: I have just updated the question to include dashboard index page.

Comment: Indeed, looks like variables are there. In which case, routing is the suspect. Are you sure you properly invoke `dashboard#index` page? Let's look at the request log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it to work.

**I needed to implement service objects using Plain Old Ruby Objects.**
For each for the actions, I placed them in a separate service, and then called them in the controllers.

The steps are

1. Create a folder under the app directory of the application named
   **services**.
2. Create individual services for each of the controller actions.
3. Call each service that you want on the controller.

That's all.

Comment: But what was the actual problem? This would not be needed if you indeed requested `dashboard#index` action directly and rendered its view. Was it indeed a routing problem (that is, you were hitting another controller instead?)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this out.

Controllers and models have a folder called **concerns** where you can keep codes that you want to be shared by different controllers and/or models.

Simply move the code that you want to share to the concerns folder, and then call them on each model.

You can define the code in the concerns folder using modules.